# Editar por linea de comando un archivo txt

Tags: cmd, batch

Necesito modificar la linea 5 y la linea 15 en un archivo .txt mediante un .bat modificando la fecha del día.

Los datos a modificar serian los siguientes:

```
HostFile=BIBLIOTECA/ARCHIVOddmmaa
PCFile=\\servidor\carpeta\subcarpeta\ARCHIVOddmmaa
```

En el cual agregue automáticamente la fecha de hoy al nombre del archivo, por ejemplo:

```
HostFile=BIBLIOTECA/ARCHIVO220817
PCFile=\\servidor\carpeta\subcarpeta\ARCHIVO220817
```

Ésta sería la estructura del archivo a modificar:

```
[DataTransferFromAS400]
Version=2.0
[HostInfo]
Database=*SYSBAS
HostFile=BIBLIOTECA/ARCHIVOddmmaa
HostName=
[ClientInfo]
ASCIITruncation=1
ConvType=0
CrtOpt=1
FDFFile=
FDFFormat=1
FileOps=503209343
OutputDevice=2
PCFile=\\servidor\carpeta\subcarpeta\ARCHIVOddmmaa
PCFileType=1
SaveFDF=0
```

El código para establecer la fecha en una variable ya lo tengo:

```
set aa=%date:~8,4%
set mm=%date:~3,2%
set dd=%date:~0,2%
```

Me faltaría cómo editar las líneas 5 y 15 en el archivo .txt; ¿Cómo sería?

Comment: Deberías explicar más en detalle que es un archivo `.tto`, no todos en el sitio tenemos contacto con la plataforma AS/400, también sería útil que agregues un link a un archivo de ejemplo e indicar en la pregunta que se trataría de un archivo en codificación EBCDIC ( me imagino). Tal vez reformulando la pregunta sea más claro para todos y no termine cerrada, en definitiva es un problema de edición de un archivo por línea de comandos. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias Patricio, hice las modificaciones que mencionaste, para que sea mas fácil de comprender, lo que estaría necesitando es modificar registros en el archivo mediante un .bat

Comment: Clarísimo Jimmy, hay posibilidad de usar alguna herramienta externa como `sed` o necesitas una solución pura en modo `BATCH`?

Answer (score 1):

Este programa Batch modifica tu archivo en la forma descrita:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "fecha=%date:~0,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~8,4%"

(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" input.txt') do (
   set "line=%%b"
   if %%a equ 5 (
      set "line=!line:ddmmaa=%fecha%!"
   ) else if %%a equ 15 (
      set "line=!line:ddmmaa=%fecha%!"
   )
   echo !line!
)) > output.txt
move /Y input.txt output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Haz tres archivos, uno que tenga las líneas 1-4, otro que tenga de la 6 a la 14 y otro que tenga de la 16 al final.

- Luego copia el primer archivo a tu archivo destino
- Luego agrega al destino final la línea 5 con la fecha editada
- Luego agrega el segundo archivo al archivo destino
- Luego agrega la línea 15 editada al archivo destino
- Luego agrega el tercer archivo al archivo destino

Comment: Esta respuesta está _muy_ incompleta. El dato de entrada es un archivo, pero en tu respuesta no explicas cómo obtener cada uno de los pasos que mencionas. Esta respuesta es similar a decir: "Haz un nuevo archivo con las líneas 5 y 15 con la fecha editada"; fácil ¿no? Es sólo mi opinión...